# Return updated item from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

Let's say I have a really simple object which I display in a list in a WPF application. The object looks like this:

```
class Student 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    // ...some addtional properties, of course

    // Status could be Active, InActive, OnBreak, etc.
    public int StudentStatusId { get; set; }
    public StudentStatusModel { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I make a method for changing the student status via Entity Framework (or any other ORM I guess), it could look something like this:

```
class StudentService 
{
    public async Task ChangeStudentStatus(int studentId, int newStatusId)
    {
        var student = GetStudent(studentId); // Method which returns the student by id via EF
        student.StudentId = newStudentId;    // Change the student property
        await UpdateStudent(student);        // Method which updates the enity in EF and saves changes
    }
}
```

The problem is if I call my `ChangeStatus()` method, then my database will be fine, but the collection in my application will be broken, like this:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public List<StudentModel> Students { get; set; }
    public StudentModel SelectedStudent { get; set; }

    public ChangeSelectedStudentStatus(int status) 
    {
        var service = ServiceFactory.GetStudentService();
        await service.ChangeStatus(SelectedStudent.StudentId, status);
        // Now both SelectedStudent and Students are out of sync with database
    }
}
```

What is the best way to deal with this issue? I can think of three options, but I cannot figure out if either of them is a good solution, or if I am going about this in the wrong way entirely.

1. Make the `ChangeStatus` method return the updated entity, so it becomes `Task<StudentModel> ChangeStatus()`
2. Refresh the modified item in the `List<StudentModel> Students`
3. Refresh the entire `List<StudentModel> Students`

Should I do any of the above, or something completely different? I cannot find any good examples of this in the EF documentation.

Comment: Pass the `Student` instance in to the update method instead of a needless extra retreive?

Comment: @Jaloopa that might not be a bad idea. Do you know if the selected student is pointing to an item in the list, if set via `SelectedItem` in WPF? Or does it create a copy of the item in the list?